# Keyboard Layout doesn't match the one selected

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

Ubuntu 13.10

Sometimes when I start my Ubuntu 13.10 computer the keyboard layout doesn't match the only one which is installed and selected on my computer.

I only have the UK keyboard selected but sometimes when I start up the @ and the " key are in the wrong place. When I check in system settings the UK Keyboard is correctly selected.

The only way to get this error to correct itself is to Log Out and back in again.

I don't touch the keyboard settings and when it starts up again the keyboard layout is correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Unity or Xfce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue with Ubuntu 13.10. However I am able to resolve the situation without having to log out and back in again. If you have the "Show current input source in the menu bar" checkbox selected in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Layout Settings (a.k.a "Text Entry" settings), then even though "English (UK)" will be selected in the drop down menu when you click the icon in the menu bar, if you deselect it (by clicking on the "English (UK)" entry in the drop down list) then it will give you back your UK layout, which is a little odd. You can then reselect it if you wish and it will still be the UK layout.

I know this isn't exactly a fix, but its a little less drastic than logging out and back in again.

Comment: This solution works great. I've also found that this bug has already been reported to ubuntu so fingers crossed it should get fixed in the next release. Thanks for taking the time to reply to me.

Comment: Could you link to the bug report? I had the same problem, but for some reason this solution doesn't fix missing accent functionality (so compose + [ + u should normally give u with an umlaut). I was wondering if anyone else on the bug report mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this--at the top of your desktop is a bar that contains buttons for various services such as Bluetooth,wifi, and system power etc. There must be a button that says En2 or En1 depending on the layout you've selected. Adjust your keyboard layout using this button. A keyboard layout chart is available in the same drop-down menu which can be used as a reference.